Nginx config skipping "if" condition
I have the following snippet in my nginx config file:
set $condition 0;
if ($arg_d ~* "IY86O") {
    set $condition "A";
}
if ($request_uri !~ ^/pre-qualify) {
    set $condition "${condition}B";
}
if ($condition = "AB") {
    return 301 https://dev.domain.dev/pre-qualify/?$args&utm_term=www-to-your-prequal;
}

if ($arg_d ~* "POD-WEBSITE-LP") {
    return 301 https://test.your.domain.com/apply/pods-message.html?$args&utm_term=www-to-pods-message;
}

if ($arg_d ~* "PO63M") {
    return 301 https://test.your.domain.com/apply?$args&utm_term=www-to-your-PO63M;
}

if ($arg_dmsg = 1) {
    return 301 https://test.your.domain.com/calculator?$args&utm_term=www-to-your-dmsg;
}

if ($request_uri ~* "^/apply") {
    return 301 https://test.your.domain.com/apply?$args&utm_term=www-to-your-apply;
}

if ($request_uri ~* "^/access-offers") {
    return 301 https://test.your.domain.com/access-offers?$args&utm_term=www-to-your-access-offers;
}

if ($request_uri ~* "^/offers") {
    return 301 https://test.your.domain.com/apply?$args&utm_term=www-to-your-offers;
} 

If I try to retrieve URL https://dev.domain.dev/?d=IY86O, it operates as I intend and redirects me to https://dev.domain.dev/pre-qualify/?d=IY86O&utm_term=www-to-your-prequal. That's all good.
If I try to retrieve URL https://dev.domain.dev/apply/?d=IY86O, it redirects me to https://dev.domain.dev/apply?d=IY860&utm_term=www-to-your-apply. Not at all what I expected. In my mind it should have gone to https://dev.domain.dev/pre-qualify/?d=IY86O&utm_term=www-to-your-prequal like in the first example.
Why does the second example skip over the part of the config file that says:
set $condition 0;
if ($arg_d ~* "IY86O") {
    set $condition "A";
}
if ($request_uri !~ ^/pre-qualify) {
    set $condition "${condition}B";
}
if ($condition = "AB") {
    return 301 https://dev.domain.dev/pre-qualify/?$args&utm_term=www-to-your-prequal;
}

